# is it possible to return html dynamically from component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using leaflet. I have array of data. I use loop for that data to loop through it.

Then, I make marker from each item. Each item has some key value pairs, so depending on them, I create popups for each marker.

Right now, I have a function

```
function createString(carModel){
  let string = `<h1>this is popup content ${carModel}</h1>`
}
```

And I set this returned string into marker's setPopup function.

**Question) can't I have a component instead of that string literal creating so that I could dynamically pass carModel to it, it would return its html and I'd set it into setPopup function which leads a cleaner code. Is this possible instead of creating string/html in javascript?**

Comment: You would need to use [jsx](https://github.com/vuejs/babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx) and JSX syntax isn't nearly as simple and expressive as Vue syntax, but it's definitely more expressive than creating v-nodes using `Vue.prototype.createElement`. You'll also need a component that renders v-nodes like [so](https://pastebin.com/sXsagV8U) (you get an array of v-nodes back from a JSX expression; you then pass those v-nodes to the v-node rendering component written out in the pastebin)

Comment: I don't get how it helps me. here is how it needs to set content for popup to open. popup.setContent(marker.render())  marker.render is just my function i put into marker when creating it. how is jsx gonna help me ?

Comment: You can display raw html with [this directive](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML)

Comment: Show your code here

Comment: You asked how to return a component instead of a string. A component instance is an array of v-nodes internally. vue jsx will allow you to easily create an array of v-nodes using HTML-like syntax in JavaScript. If you just need HTML, you need to use the `v-html` directive like @PierreSaid mentioned.